# Node.js: How can I just access the “To”, “Body” and “From” fields of an e-mail received using node-imap?

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

I'm using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) to get my Gmail e-mails and although their example runs pretty well, I'm not being able to only print the `msg.To`, `msg.Body`, and `msg.From`. I can only print the entire message, which is a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: The example in the readme uses util.inspect to print out the structure of the msg object. What output did you see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for node-imap, the To and From headers are available in the `msg.headers`, which includes the To and From. In order to retrieve the body you must append a variable every time the `chunk` event is emitted, and upon `end` you should have a completed body.  The headers will probably also not be fully available until the `end` event has been triggered, so you must take that into account.